# Is there any way to Add multiple vertical axis dynamically to Line chart in Kendo ui?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-chart

Is there any way to Add multiple vertical axis dynamically to Line chart in Kendo ui?
right now am using the following snippet for 2 vertical axis in kendo ui Line chart

```
valueAxes: [{
        name: "test",
        color:"#07eeff",
              labels: {
                format: "{0}pu"
        }        
    }, {
        name: "test1",
        color:"#07eeff",
      labels: {
                format: "{0}C"
        }
    }
            ],
```

I am using the following link for reference:
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/dataviz/chart/overview#multiple-value-axes

If there is any way to Add multiple vertical axis dynamically(through JSON Data) to Line chart in Kendo-ui then please let me know.

Comment: why this was tagged with `jQuery`?

Comment: Please check the below link it will help you. Let me know if you face any issue. http://jayeshgoyani.blogspot.in/2013/05/how-to-add-multiple-lines-series.html

Comment: @JayeshGoyani:Thanks for your reply.your link is for adding multiple line series dynamically but i want multiple vertical Axis(Y-Axis) not the line series.

Comment: @user3706745, Please check below demo in my (answer) post. You may get idea how to add series and valueaxies in kendo chart. Please provide your code snippet is if you have any concern.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below code snippet and DEMO.

```
$.each(valueAxes, function (index, valueAxes) {
                            if (valueAxes.name == nodeText.trim()) {
                                checkedAxes.push(valueAxes);
                                checkedAxes.visible = true;
                            }
                        });

                        $.each(series, function (index, series) {
                            if (series.name == nodeText.trim()) {
                                checkedSeries.push(series);
                            }
                        });
                    });
```

Please check below demo for more clarification.

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/sipav/2/edit)